# Is it possible to browse a Windows 10 File History backup without setting the user account to use that backup?

Tags: windows-10, file-history

I have a Windows 10 PC with a single user account on it. This user account already has a File History backup configured and operating. I have *another* File History backup from a *different* user account from a different computer. I would like to be able to browse and extract files from that backup, and I do not want to lose my current backup configuration. I assume that I could simply create another user account on my computer and set it to use that other backup, but I would prefer not to have to do that. Is there any other way besides creating a whole new account just to browse the other backup?

Comment: The other user account backup contains the user folder and would be inaccessible to you unless you could take ownership of the backup. I don't think it likely this would work.

Comment: I have the login credentials for that other user account, if necessary.

Comment: Even so, you need take ownership of the user's documents. Having the credentials may not be enough.